# NUnit running test(s) is failing

Tags: c#, nunit

My setup

```
CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
package = new TestPackage(pathToTestDll);
builder = new TestSuiteBuilder();
suite = builder.Build(package);
```

And running (note that tests are the valid list of NUnitTestMethods retrieved from the suite

```
foreach (NUnitTestMethod t in tests)
{
    try
    {
        var res = t.RunTest();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I get this as the exception stack:

> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) at NUnit.Core.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args) at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestMethod() at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestCase(TestResult testResult)

Note that t.RunTest(); does not fail rather the test just fails at running and HasError flag is set...

The nunit.core and nunit.core.interfaces are the same files in both my test package and runner package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize CoreServices but make no use of them because you are running tests at a very low level. Using internal classes, not intended for general purpose use, is always risky. But it's especially risky if you put them together piecemeal rather than using them in the way that NUnit itself does.

If you want to run the tests programatically (that may not be such a great idea, but it appears to be what you want to do) then I suggest you select and use one of the NUnit runners to take care of the details for you. Select from SimpleTestRUnner, RemoteTestRunner or TestDomain, depending on how you want the tests to run, and where.

TestDomain will run them in a separate AppDomain, which is generally easiest and safest. RemoteTestRunner will run them in the current AppDomain, redirecting output. SimpleTestRunner is the lowest level runner (but still **way** higher-level than what you are doing) and just runs the tests where they are. Note that you can't run tests in the same AppDomain (Remote and Simple) unless you have copied all the test files, their references and the NUnit files into the same directory.

Comment: Am I able to simply run the SimpleTestRunner (after instantiation and loading my package) via runner.Run(new NullListener(),myTest.TestName)? 

Also is there any way to set a reference path to the reference/nunit files rather than filling the working directory with them?

Comment: 1.The second argument to Run must be a test filter. In your case, a SimpleNamefFilter would probably suit.

Comment: 2. No, not if you use SimpleTestRunner. You need to run in a separate AppDomain if you want your tests to be in a different place from the nunit files. That's how NUnit does it. IIRC (this is very old code you are using) RemoteTestRunner will let you do that if you create an AppDomain. TestDomain will do it for you, which is simpler.

Comment: BTW, youn ever said __why__ you are doing this and I never asked. However, it does seem a little crazy to be writing your own runner when NUnit is happy to run the tests for you. :-)

Comment: Writing an application to search/run nunit tests based on method attributes other than the category and method signature (IE need to find key words in a description attribute). After custom lists can be crated, running the tests needs to be able to export the results to TestRail via another custom attribute holding the ID. Automating the QA process. 1200 Tests.Thank you for your answer though it had solved my issue

Comment: You can use the NUnit 3 console runner with it's `--where` option to select tests with a description property using a regular expression and create a list of them. If you can't figure it out from the docs, ask another question. :-)